# Get keyboard event in purescript

Tags: purescript, purescript-halogen

I want to get keydown event in purescript so I used DomEvent.
Here is my code.

```
main :: Eff (HA.HalogenEffects (console :: CONSOLE, timer :: T.TIMER)) Unit
main = HA.runHalogenAff do
  body <- HA.awaitBody
  cube <- runUI C.cubes unit body
  documenttarget <- liftEff $ window >>= document <#> DHT.htmlDocumentToEventTarget
  addEventListener (EventType "keydown") (eventListener test) true (documenttarget)

  H.liftEff $ T.setInterval (1000 / frameRate) do
    HA.runHalogenAff $ cube.query $ H.action C.Tick
```

When I try to run this code, I am getting error like this.

```
documenttarget <- liftEff $ window >>= document <#> DHT.htmlDocumentToEventTarget
Coudn't match type Eff with type Aff
```

I know aff and eff but I am new to purescript so I am not sure what I have to do to fix this issue.
What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

The block that you pass to `halogenRunAff` is an `Aff` block, so every line in it must be an `Aff`. But `liftEff` returns an `Eff` instead. So there is a mismatch.

This is what the compiler is telling you: "can't match Eff with Aff".

To fix this, replace `liftEff` with `liftAff`:

```
documenttarget <- liftAff $ window >>= document <#> DHT.htmlDocumentToEventTarget
```